# What Adobe program allows me to create animations?

Tags: adobe-flash

I remember that back in 2006, in web design, I learned how to produce flash games using an Adobe Flash program. Here we are in 2014, and I have no idea which program out of Adobe's entire creative suite does this anymore.

My goal is to create a working UI using Flash to present to my company. Does Adobe still have something that can do this and will let me load in objects for use as menu items, etc.?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You mean, like, [Adobe Flash](http://www.adobe.com/products/flash.html)?

Note that there is no Creative Suite anymore. It's Creative Cloud now, with a subscription-based payment model.

Comment: I was hoping to avoid paying a subscription model for a single program. Any alternatives?

Comment: @HAL "Any alternatives?" Yeah, dump that proprietary Flash stuff and consider using [HTML5 technologies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_HTML5_and_Flash) instead.

Comment: @HAL You may still find shops that sell old CS licenses. Or like Techie007 said, use HTML5. Or http://alternativeto.net/software/adobe-flash/

Comment: I believe I can use Stencyl to perform this, its simple if/then statements for most of it. None of this has to be view able via browser. Thank you for the suggestions! No thank you to anyone who left -'s without constructive feedback.

Comment: @HAL The downvotes are due to lack of research effort, I presume, also given that the answer to the question was quite obvious.

Comment: @slhck, First look at Professional CC's interface it was not apparently obvious that the program would perform similar to macromedia flash. I wasn't willing to spend the money without first being assured.